# Datepicker Clears Modal Data Value

Tags: jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-modal

I have a foreach loop with buttons which trigger a modal. The modal has a form which includes a datepicker input field. For convenience, some of the other form fields are prefilled with variables from the initial trigger button. However when I select the datepicker all other input fields are wiped. I assume this is because my datepicker event is overwriting my data fields, but can't figure out how to get them both in harmony.

I've tried reordering date picker and modal event, and have followed other examples with various datepicker versions but to no success. I can put other none datepicker fields in which don't cause an issue.

```
Version: bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/
```

the trigger button with some variables:

```
<button data-toggle='modal' data-one='{$row['thingone']}' data-two='{$row['thingtwo']}' data-target='#myModal'>The Button</button>
```

the form in my modal:

```
<form method='post' action=''>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>One Thing</th>
                <th>Two Things</th>
                <th>The Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id='myModalbody'>                               
            <tr>
                <td><input class='form-control' type='text' name='one' id='one' ></td>
                <td><input class='form-control' type='text' name='two' id='two' ></td>
                <td><input class='form-control' id='the_date' type='text' data-date-format="yyyy/mm/dd" name='the_date' ></td>
            </tr>                               
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Update </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

and my script at the end of the page for this iteration:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

    var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
    var one    = button.data('one') //info from data-*
    var two    = button.data('two')
    var modal  = $(this)
    modal.find('.modal-body #one').val(one)
    modal.find('.modal-body #two').val(two)

    $('input[name="the_date"]').datepicker({                
        format: "yyyy/mm/dd",           
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true
    });

})
```

Data thing one and thing two populates to their respective fields correctly, but clicking on the datepicker input field deletes the other fields if they've been populated from the trigger button.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: We can be a little tricky and set other filed's value's again when datepickers 'onDateChange' event triggered.
[documentation](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/events.html#changedate)

Comment: Might be a good work around until I can figure out something cleaner thanks!

Comment: Your selector `$('input[name="the_date"]')` might be ambigious, I believe the right way to use it would be without the double quotes `$('input[name=the_date]')`

Comment: removing the double quotes gives the same results, I also tried using: `#the_date` but most examples I came across used the double quotes method..

Comment: It seems that when the date picker is getting focused the modal show function is getting triggered. You can move the datepicker initialization out from the function and add  a check `if(!event.relatedTarget) return;` at the top of the function.

Comment: Thanks Suraj, I did something similar to your suggestion and got it working! If you want to post an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to @suraj's suggestion in the comments I simply put a check at the beginning of my function which solved the issue of wiping the other fields when selecting the date input. It doesn't matter for the result if datepicker is in or out of the main function.

```
 if ( event.relatedTarget != null) {
     var button     = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
 }
```

Using: `alert (event.relatedTarget)` in my show function I realised that the entire function was being re triggered by the date field, only when using the `.datepicker`, which would result in `event.relatedTarget` being null, because obviously the data info for the other fields isn't stored in the datepicker, and because it re-triggers the function, it would update the find fields with the new empty data.

The above snippet prevents the variables from being rewritten as null when datepicker is selected, but the show function still runs again when datepicker is selected, only now it doesn't change any input data.

I still don't fully understand why the show modal is triggered again by the datepicker, but this is the most simple workaround I've found until I can better understand what's going on...